# how to create interactions with quanteda?

Tags: r, quanteda

Consider the following example

```
library(quanteda)
library(tidyverse)

tibble(text = c('the dog is growing tall',
                'the grass is growing as well')) %>% 
  corpus() %>% dfm()
Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 8 features (31.2% sparse).
       features
docs    the dog is growing tall grass as well
  text1   1   1  1       1    1     0  0    0
  text2   1   0  1       1    0     1  1    1
```

I would like to create an interaction between `dog` and the other tokens in each sentence. That is, creating the features `the-dog`, `is-dog`, `growing-dog`, `tall-dog` and adding them to the `dfm` (on top of the ones we already have).

That is, for instance, `the-dog` would be equal to 1 if both `the` and `dog` are present in the sentence (and zero otherwise). So `the-dog` would be one for the first sentence and zero for the second one.

Notice how I only create interaction terms when `dog` is in the sentence, so `dog-grass` is not required here.

How can I do that efficiently in `quanteda`?

Comment: What format of output do you want? A document by term-dog occurrence, with no other features counted?

Comment: thank you @KenBenoit. I think a dfm would be great. So the DFM would have the following columns in our example `the`, `dog`, `is`, `growing`, `tall`, `grass`, `as`, `well` and `the-dog`, `is-dog`, `growing-dog`, `tall-dog`. I was thinking these variables could be created at the `tokens()` level but I am not sure how (`tokens_skipgram()` would create many irrelevant interactions here)

Comment: so the rule would be: if the sentence (quanteda document that is) contains `dog`, then interact all tokens in the sentence with `dog`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.1.2

toks <- tokens(c(
  "the dog is growing tall",
  "the grass is growing as well"
))

# now keep just tokens co-occurring with "dog"
toks_dog <- tokens_select(toks, "dog", window = 1e5)

# create the dfm and label other terms as interactions with dog
dfmat_dog <- dfm(toks_dog) %>%
  dfm_remove("dog")
colnames(dfmat_dog) <- paste(featnames(dfmat_dog), "dog", sep = "-")
dfmat_dog
## Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 4 features (50.00% sparse) and 0 docvars.
##        features
## docs    the-dog is-dog growing-dog tall-dog
##   text1       1      1           1        1
##   text2       0      0           0        0

# combine with other features
print(cbind(dfm(toks), dfmat_dog), max_nfeat = -1)
## Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 12 features (37.50% sparse) and 0 docvars.
##        features
## docs    the dog is growing tall grass as well the-dog is-dog growing-dog
##   text1   1   1  1       1    1     0  0    0       1      1           1
##   text2   1   0  1       1    0     1  1    1       0      0           0
##        features
## docs    tall-dog
##   text1        1
##   text2        0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I know realize there could be issues later on if the two dfms in the `cbind` call contain overlapping column names (i.e. words). Can we cbind dfms and avoid duplication?

Comment: Yes, just call `dfm_compress()` on the cbind-ed dfm, it will combine the duplicated features.